# Javascript custom sorting an array of objects by year with 'pre year'

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

So I have an array of objects ex:

```
var a = {user: [
 {year:'1950',name:'Joe'},
 {year:'19XX',name:'Chris'},
 {year:'1980',name:'Bob'},
 {year:'1955',name:'Jan'}
]}
```

I use this data to template out simple elements holding the year and name. 
I also have option via a select element to sort this data and then use the sorted to template it out again in order of sort. (bob,chris,jan,joe) or year. 
But my issue starts with year.

I am needing to continue to use a simple plugin jsonQ (http://ignitersworld.com/lab/jsonQ.html)
to edit and sort data, and need to have data for year actually be a little different than desc or asc.

1st I need to edit data at various parts, like year (19XX should become 'Pre 1950'):

```
//inside ajax success function
var dataObj = jsonQ(data);

dataObj.find('year').value(function (data){
   if (data == '19XX') {
       return 'pre 1953'
   } else {
       return data;
   }
});
```

Now I will have a final product data set that needs to be sorted.

```
var orderedData = dataObj.sort('year', {'order' : 'ASC'});
```

But this gives me the data back as:

```
{
 user: [
  {year:'1950',name:'Joe'},
  {year:'1955',name:'Jan'},     
  {year:'1980',name:'Bob'},
  {year:'Pre 1950',name:'Chris'}
 ]
}
```

What I need is the data to be returned as:

```
{
 user: [
  {year:'Pre 1950',name:'Chris'},
  {year:'1950',name:'Joe'},
  {year:'1955',name:'Jan'},     
  {year:'1980',name:'Bob'}
 ]
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to define your own compairing function. Actually P is lexicographically bigger than any digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the solution, shortly after posting, while using the plugin. (which is what I wanted, Sorry, I should have specified that more).

My problem was in my options passed into the plugin's `sort()`method.
not easy to find since documentation isn't 100.

```
var orderedData = dataObj.sort('year', {
  'order' : 'ASC',
  logic: function(val){
     return (val == 'pre 1950') ? '1911' : val;
  }
});
```

What this is essentially doing is replacing 'pre 1950' with 1911, just for sorting purposes.

Comment: you could skip paranteses around the condition.

Comment: @NinaScholz - you are right .. old habits die hard :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can implement your own sorting criterion, and pass it to `Array.sort()`.

This criterion takes the form of a `function(a, b)` that returns a number:

- **Negative** if `a` should go before `b` in the sorted list
- **Zero** if `a` and `b` are essentially equal
- **Postive** if `a` should go after `b`

This may look pretty arbitrary, but think about it this way: in the simple case of sorting numbers from lesser to greater, the function returns `a - b`. So, `f(a, b)` is `a - b`, and `a - b < 0` means `a < b`.

Back to your case. Let's implement a criterion function that sorts the years from lesser to greater, putting `Pre 1950` at the top:

```
function byYear(a, b) {
  if (a === "Pre 1950") return -1 // a goes before
  if (b === "Pre 1950") return 1  // b goes before

  return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b) // lesser goes before
})
```

Try it in the browser console:

```
> ["1980", "1970", "Pre 1950"].sort(byYear)
["Pre 1950", "1970", "1980"]
```

Given that you're sorting objects, you'll need to adapt the criterion function above to work with `a.year` and `b.year`.

Comment: The `if (a === "Pre 1950") return -1;` part is not necessary.

Comment: I guess you have a point. +1 for the detailed answer. Great job.

Comment: @slezica - Yea, +1 this is a great answer for understanding this kind of manipulation .. I was stuck with this plugin specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the array in three steps

- sort priority years, like `19XX`
- sort by years without priority
- sort by name.

```js
var a = { user: [{ year: '1950', name: 'Joe' }, { year: '19XX', name: 'Chris' }, { year: '1980', name: 'Bob' }, { year: '1955', name: 'Jan' }] };

a.user.sort(function (a, b) {
    var order = { '19XX': -1 };
    return (order[a.year] || 0) - (order[b.year] || 0) || a.year - b.year || a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});

console.log(a);
```